# Rotating announcements for custom Windows 11 widget

Tags: c#, widget, windows-11, windows-app-sdk

I read [user doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/stay-up-to-date-with-widgets-7ba79aaa-dac6-4687-b460-ad16a06be6e4) about Windows 11 widgets. It mentions the rotating announcements. When your widget can appear on some time instead of wether widget on the taskbar.

[image]

I read [developer doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/widgets/widget-providers), and it does not have any mention about rotating announcements.

How can I implement the rotating announcements for my windows 11 widget?

Answer (score 0):

`Rotating announcements` and `Badging` are the behaviors of the Widget notifications. As far as I'm concerned, there is no way implement the rotating announcements for the widget. It is out of the scope of the implement a widget provider. If you want to turn on the Rotating announcements, you could try to click on the profile picture icon to open Widget settings and then turn on `Show announcements` options under the Widget taskbar behaviors.

Comment: What's the point of these settings if third-party widgets cannot use this functionality?

Comment: For the third-party widgets, you could try to add the third-party widgets to the widgets board. And then turn on the `Show announcements options`.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar capability to make a more useful meeting bar widget like https://meetingbar.app

@Jeaninez-MSFT is there any plans to enable third-party widgets to make announcements, notifications, or push content into the taskbar area?